# Entity Framework DbContext Where In Query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to query an Entity/Table and determine if a record exist that matches a list of items.

In other words I have an array of names, I want to build my query to do something like:

```
string[] fileList = {"Clients", "Jobs", "People"};
ICollection<DocumentsView> documentList = await _dataContext.FindAllAsync<DocumentsView>(fileList.Containts(a.name)));
```

The above obviously doesn't work, but is there some way to do that?
I'm currently doing this, and it's working, but there has to be a better way...what if I wanted to extend the list of items to compare?  etc.

```
ICollection<DocumentsView> documentList = await _dataContext.FindAllAsync<DocumentsView>(a=>a.name == "Clients" && a.name == "Jobs" && a.name == "People");
```

Here is my FindAllAsync method for the DbContext query:

```
public async Task<ICollection<T>> FindAllAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match) where T : class
{
    return await _context.Set<T>().Where(match).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Isn't your lambda missing `a =>` in first code snippet? `await _dataContext.FindAllAsync<DocumentsView>(a => fileList.Containts(a.name));`

Comment: It also uses "Containts" instead of "Contains".

Comment: Well..yes it is, and that works just fine.  I tried using (fileList.Contains(a=>a.name)) which obviously didn't work.  Lol, thanks!  If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @JonathanM I didn't copy/paste this, I just retyped, so it's not that way in my code, but thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Contains` call should work just fine, Entity Framework will transform it into `IN ()` clause when generating SQL query.

However, your code is missing `a =>` when you try to call `Contains`:

```
await _dataContext.FindAllAsync<DocumentsView>(a => fileList.Contains(a.name)));
```